# Mysql: SIGNAL SQLSTATE is preventing the data to be inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a before trigger which prevents data to be updated into table. For this I used  "SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This operation is not allowed.';".
At the same time also want to insert the data into another table.
But it is preventing that data to be inserted. My code is as below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_RESTRICT_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON AUDIT_DATA  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN


   INSERT INTO AUDIT_DATA_OTHER
           (PRACTICE_GROUP_ID
           ,AUDIT_TYPE
           ,AUDIT_SUB_TYPE
           ,AUDIT_SOURCE
           ,EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_TYPE
           ,AUDIT_DATA
           ,FOUND_SET_AUDIT_DATA
           ,OWNER_TYPE
           ,OWNER_ID
           ,CUSTOMER_ID
           ,PATIENT_NUMBER
           ,PATIENT_FIRST_NAME
           ,PATIENT_LAST_NAME
           ,PATIENT_MIDDLE_NAME
           ,PATIENT_BIRTH_DATE
           ,AUDIT_INFO
           ,IP_ADDRESS
           ,WORKSTATION_NAME
           ,CREATE_BY
           ,CREATE_DATE
           ,CREATE_PROCESS
           ,USERNAME
           ,IS_EMERGENCY_MODE
           ,EMERGENCY_NOTES
           ,EMERGENCY_FIRST_NAME
           ,EMERGENCY_LAST_NAME
           ,ENCOUNTER_TYPE
           ,ENCOUNTER_DATE
           ,ENCRYPTED_AUDIT_DATA)
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'AttemptToModifyAuditRecord'
           ,'Update'
           ,'MAXIMEYES_APPLICATION'
           ,''
           ,NULL
           ,''
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,'SQL query which attempted to execute:Update'
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,-1
           ,NOW()
           ,1
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL);


SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This operation is not allowed.';


END $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception raised in the trigger effectively stops and rolls back any transaction, therefore it will roll back the insertion to the log table as well - provided the log table is also transactional.

As [MySQL documentation on triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) says:

> The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction, such as START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK

Therefore, the only real chance you have is to use a non/transactional log table, such as a myisam table because the rollback does not apply to that insertion.